# Use LINQ to filter SftpFile based on separate given extension array

Tags: c#, linq, ssh.net

I am working on .NET CORE 6 solution. I have list of sftpFile `SSH.NET` along with each extension and another list of extensions i.e. .csv. I want to LINQ to filter files from list 1 based on list 2. i.e. if list 2 have .csv & .txt then LINQ should filter out only .csv and .txt files. I did implement solution but it is using loop. sftpFile object has property name which is actual file name so the compassion will be on that

I get the fileName only with the following code but I need `list<sftpFile>`

```
var exceptRejectedFileNames2 =  sftpFiles.Select(x => x.Name).Except(RejectedFileName.GetNames()).ToList();
```

filter method as below;

```
public static class RejectedFileName
{
    private static readonly string[] FileNames = {".", ".."};

    public static string[] GetNames()
    {
        return FileNames;
    }
}
```

Comment: `sftpFiles.Where(x => !RejectedFileName.GetNames().Contains(x.Name)).ToList()`, you might want to think about changing `GetNames` to return a `HashSet<string>`

Comment: Again, I highly recommend you change `GetNames` to return a `HashSet`, because right now you're iterating over the entire `GetNames` array for every file on the SFTP server, this can balloon out of control very quickly (i.e for say 100 files, and 20 to ignore, that'd be 2000 iterations already and those are quite small starting numbers), in turn a `HashSet` is optimised for lookup speed, i.e it's a lot faster at checking if it contains a given object or not

Comment: I change to HashSet, refer to my answer .. many thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class RejectedFileName
{
    private static readonly HashSet<string> FileNames = new HashSet<string>() { ".", ".." };

    public static HashSet<string> GetNames()
    {
        return FileNames;
    }
}
```

then in service class

```
var files = sftpFiles.Where(x => !RejectedFileName.GetNames().Contains(x.Name)).ToList();
```